# Issue update from Angular 10 to 11 cannot access parent

Tags: angular

I am running into this issue when trying to update from angular 10 to 11. The project was originally an Angular 7 project but I have been following the steps in the official update guide and am trying to get it updated to Angular 15 but ran into this issue along the way.

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 10.2.4
Node: 12.11.1
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.2.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1002.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1002.4
@angular-devkit/core               10.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics         10.2.4
@angular/cdk                       10.2.7
@angular/cli                       10.2.4
@angular/material                  10.2.7
@angular/material-moment-adapter   10.2.7
@schematics/angular                10.2.4
@schematics/update                 0.1002.4
rxjs                               6.6.7
typescript                         4.0.8
```

This is myng version ^

This is the error I get when I run `sudo npm run-script ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11`

```
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 11.2.19 to perform the update.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
An unhandled exception occurred: npm WARN deprecated @schematics/update@0.1102.19: This was an internal-only Angular package up through Angular v11 which is no longer used or maintained. Upgrade Angular to v12+ to remove this dependency.
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
internal/process/main_thread_only.js:42
    cachedCwd = binding.cwd();
                        ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, uv_cwd
    at process.cwd (internal/process/main_thread_only.js:42:25)
    at Object.resolve (path.js:979:47)
    at patchProcessObject (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:74:28)
    at prepareMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:11:3)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:7:1 {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'uv_cwd'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @angular/cli@11.2.19 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@11.2.19 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Im running node 12.11.1

Any ideas? Ive tried running it with `--force`. Ive tried installing a fresh node. Ive tried deleting my node module folder and running `npm install`

Comment: `shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied` are the permissions of your folder in order for the user? This looks to be the culprit.

Comment: @xtj7 the permissions werent specifically locked down by me and im using sudo... it should have permission